# How to parse this input from user to figure where to print the results in C?

Tags: c, io

Problem: the user should be able to choose how many generated sentences s/he wants, and to choose between printing the outputs to a text file or to the terminal screen (input example: 4 c.txt), so if the user didn't choose a file name, then the output should be displayed on the terminal.

However, I couldn't figure out the way to solve these two problems.

1- how to parse inNum and the file name(str) from the input.

2- allowing user to choose between printing the output in a text file, or printing it in the terminal.

This is my code in C language:

```
FILE *fileptr;
char str[50];
printf("Enter # then str:\n");
scanf("%d %s",&inNum,&str);    
fileptr = fopen(str, "w");
if(fileptr == NULL)
{
  for(n=0;n<inNum;n++)
    {
        printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n",article[rand()%5],noun[rand()%5],verb[rand()%5],preposition[rand()%5],article[rand()%5],noun[rand()%5]);
    }
}
else
{
    for(int n=0;n<inNum;n++)
    {
        fprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n",article[rand()%5],noun[rand()%5],verb[rand()%5],preposition[rand()%5],article[rand()%5],noun[rand()%5]);
    }
}
fclose(fileptr);

return 0;
```

Comment: First, how do you _expect_ the user to tell the program that the output should go to the console? Please give an example of such user input.

Comment: if the user input a file name such as (file.txt), then the output should go to the output  file. If the users did not specify which file, then the output should go to console.

Answer (score 0):

To write to a named file or `stdout` (by default if no output filename is given) is relatively easy. The key is to read the complete line of input as a single line and parse with `sscanf` rather than trying to read with `scanf` (which will block waiting for input if an input is missing)

When reading user input, don't skimp on buffer size. For the line of input, use some reasonable size `1024` or so. You can size the input and output filenames to `50` if you can guarantee that the names will never exceed `49` chars, otherwise include `limits.h` and use the macro `PATH_MAX` to size the filename buffers which will guarantee sufficient size to hold the largest filename acceptable by the system.

(**remember:** you would rather the buffer be `10,000` characters **too long** than `1` character **too short**)

That in mind you can do something like the following which requires at least the number of lines and the input filename be given by the user, and will write to the output filename (if given), otherwise it will write the lines to `stdout` by default:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC   50   /* if you need a constanst, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXB 1024   /* size of read buffer (don't skimp!) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXB] = "",    /* buffer to hold lines read */
        ifn[MAXC] = "",     /* input filename */
        ofn[MAXC] = "";     /* output filename */
    FILE *ifp = NULL,       /* in file pointer */
        *ofp = stdout;      /* out file pointer (initialized to stdout) */
    int n = 0,              /* number of lines to display */
        cnt = 0,            /* count of lines output */
        rtn = 0;            /* sscanf return */

    printf ("enter # then filename [outfile (stdout)]: ");
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXB, stdin)) {    /* read complete line of input */
        fputs ("user canceled input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    /* parse line of input into n, ifn, and ofn */
    rtn = sscanf (buf, "%d %s %s", &n, ifn, ofn);

    if (rtn < 2) {  /* if not n and infile name, handle error */
        fputs ("error: insufficient input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(ifp = fopen (ifn, "r"))) {    /* open infile/validate open */
        perror ("fopen-str");
        return 1;
    }

    if (rtn == 3) {     /* if outfile provided, open/validate open */
        if (!(ofp = fopen (ofn, "w"))) {
            perror ("fopen-ofn");  /* show error, write to stdout (default) */
            fputs ("warning: writing to stdout by default.\n", stderr);
        }
    }

    while (cnt < n && fgets (buf, MAXB, ifp)) { /* read up to n lines */
        fputs (buf, ofp);   /* output to ofp (which can be stdout) */
        cnt++;              /* increment line count */
    }

    fclose (ifp);           /* close input file */
    if (ofp != stdout)      /* if output file not stdout */
        if (fclose (ofp) == EOF)    /* validate close-after-write */
            perror ("fclose(ofp)"); /* to catch stream and unreported err */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output (to `stdout` by default)**

```
$ ./bin/outputnlines
enter # then filename [outfile (stdout)]: 3 dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
```

**Example Use/Output to File**

```
$ ./bin/outputnlines
enter # then filename [outfile (stdout)]: 3 dat/captnjack.txt dat/cjout3.txt
```

**File Contents**

```
$ cat dat/cjout3.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.